# reCaptcha: error code "invalid-keys"

Tags: php, recaptcha

I currently implementing the reCaptcha for an form with HTML and PHP. The client-side solution works without any problems. But the server side fails with the validation.

So here is my server side code:

```
$data = array(
    "secret" => "MY_SECRET_KEY",
    "response" => $captcha_response,
    "remoteip" => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
);
$opts = [
    "http" => [
        "method" => "POST",
        "header" => "Accept-language: en",
        "content" => http_build_query($data)
    ]
];

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify', false, $context), true);
```

So now when I dump the result I get the following output:

```
array(4) {
  ["success"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["challenge_ts"]=>
  string(20) "2017-06-22T13:14:50Z"
  ["hostname"]=>
  string(9) "localhost"
  ["error-codes"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(12) "invalid-keys"
  }
}
```

I'm sure that the response code will completly send to the PHP script.

I also searched in the API docs, but only find these [error codes](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify#error-code-reference) and nothing matches with `invalid-keys`.

What did I wrong?

Comment: it will giving the error `invalid-keys` or `Invalid site key`

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Narayan. I get `invalid-keys`. This is an original dump from the reponse I get from Google.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

So dumb. I took the secret key from the **wrong project** from the [admin console](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin#list). The wrong project not white listed `localhost`, which I needed. Also the public-site-key and secret-key were mismatched (but both individually valid).

Comment: Thanks for the info. Seems like they should still have the error code listed in their docs (which they don't), and also give a better error message.

Answer (score 18):

I can confirm, the error-code `invalid-keys` only returns when an existing, but incorrect account or project secret key is used.

If the secret key is invalid or malformed, an error-code `invalid-input-secret` will be returned.

In our case, our Wordpress production environment had a plugin that defined a constant we were using with an incorrect secret key from a different account.

Answer (score 0):

If the google reCaptcha created and use immediately then you should got

error: `invalid-keys`

So,Wait for some hours and then used same credential